# I have changed my local react files/components and in web i don't see those changes

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

I have changed my local react files/components and in web i don't see those changes.When i do npm start again, local changes are building successfully. Can someone explain me and why it is happening how can i fix this issue.

Comment: Well when you make changes, you have to rebuild your app to reflect them. You haven't given any info about your environment or scripts, but I'm guessing running `npm start` is both rebuilding and re-running your dev server. If you want your app to automatically rebuild when you change your react files, look into Hot Module Reloading. It comes out of the box with certain build tools like `react-scripts` and `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: Thanks For sharing the info. If i install HMR will it fix my issue ?